# Using RStudio, Google Drive Desktop, Shiny, and the new R 4.3.0 placeholder feature together causes apps to crash; why is this?

Tags: r, shiny

Yes, I know R projects are not meant to be created in network drives, and I definitely will learn how to use Git properly because of this problem described below. But avoiding the problem itself is easy; I want to know its **cause**, and if possible, **why exactly it is dangerous to use RStudio and Google Drive Desktop together**.

#### Problem description

In R 4.3.0, an 'experimental feature' has been added for the native pipe (`|>`) placeholder (`_`):

> As an experimental feature the placeholder _ can now also be used in the rhs of a forward pipe |> expression as the first argument in an extraction call, such as _$coef. More generally, it can be used as the head of a chain of extractions, such as _$coef[[2]]. ([link](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-4.3.0.html))

This syntax works well except when used inside a shiny app. Below is an example code of no practical use:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput('col', 'Select column to view', choices = names(mtcars)),
  tableOutput('table')
)

server <- function (input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable(mtcars |> _[[input$col]][1:10])
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Launch the app by clicking 'Run App' in RStudio then change the focus back to RStudio, and **the app will immediately close (*)**. Try the same thing in an R project located in a network drive (*e. g.*, Google drive desktop in my case) and additional anomalies can be observed: clicking on 'Run App' variably results in either the app launching successfully, nothing happening, or an unresponsive gray window appearing.

#### What I tried

The phenomenon does not occur when...

- the new syntax is replaced with the old `mtcars[[input$col]]`,
- the new syntax is used in an R script or document that is not a Shiny app, or
- the Shiny app is launched from the R terminal, not RStudio.

Also, as mentioned above, when the app is located in a local folder, only phenomenon (*) occurs and the more peculiar anomalies cannot be seen.

#### What I want to know

Avoiding the problem is easy; I just have to either quit using RStudio to access remotely located projects, or simply paraphrase the relevant sections of code. But I want to know what exactly is going on.

I have heard it is bad practice to use RStudio together with Google Drive Desktop, but never exactly understood why; up until this point I have faced no difficulty whatsoever working in that way. The particular combination of Shiny and the new placeholder syntax must be highlighting some incompatibility between RStudio, Google Drive Desktop. I wish to know what it is.

Also, phenomenon (*) can be reproduced even in local projects. Although it is innocuous, it is certainly unusual. So I suspect that working with a remote RStudio project is not entirely responsible for the problem, and there is some genuine mismatch between Shiny and the new placeholder syntax.

#### What I observed

The problem is not dependent on the relevant code being executed. Placing the following code inside `renderTable()` of the above example produces the same phenomena.

```r
if (TRUE) {
  mtcars[[input$col]][1:10]
} else {
  mtcars |> _[[input$col]][1:10]
}
```

The phenomenon is extremely variable. I tried `set.seed()` but the outcome of pressing 'Run App' does not seem to depend on the seed. I managed to coax out the following error message after many iterations, but cannot comprehend the meaning.

```
Error in base::suppressWarnings(base::try("_"[[input$col]], silent = TRUE)) : 
  invalid use of pipe placeholder (<input>:1:0)
Warning: stack imbalance in '<-', 37 then 32
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 33 then 28

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6972
```

#### Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.utf8    

time zone: Asia/Seoul
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.7.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.31    later_1.3.1      R6_2.5.1         httpuv_1.6.11    fastmap_1.1.1    magrittr_2.0.3  
 [7] cachem_1.0.8     memoise_2.0.1    htmltools_0.5.5  lifecycle_1.0.3  promises_1.2.0.1 cli_3.6.1       
[13] xtable_1.8-4     sass_0.4.6       jquerylib_0.1.4  withr_2.5.0      compiler_4.3.0   rstudioapi_0.14 
[19] tools_4.3.0      bslib_0.4.2      ellipsis_0.3.2   mime_0.12        Rcpp_1.0.10      jsonlite_1.8.4  
[25] rlang_1.1.1
```

Comment: What version of RStudio are you running? Are you using 2023.03.0?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, the version information is as follows:

RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom" Release (3c53477afb13ab959aeb5b34df1f10c237b256c3, 2023-03-09) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.0+386 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

Comment: @MrFlick And the problem persists even after updating RStudio today... (new version info: RStudio 2023.03.1+446 "Cherry Blossom" Release (6e31ffc3ef2a1f81d377eeccab71ddc11cfbd29e, 2023-05-09) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.1+446 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36)

Comment: Maybe ask at https://community.rstudio.com/ since this seems specific to rstudio.

Comment: Posted here https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-google-drive-desktop-shiny-and-the-new-r-4-3-0-placeholder-feature-together-causes-apps-to-crash-why-is-this/166266